# $E[X(X-1)...(X-k+1)]=\lambda^k$ where $X$ is Poisson random variable

Tags: probability

> Let $X$ be a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda$, prove that $E[X(X-1)...(X-k+1)]=\lambda^k$ for $k = 2,3,...$

I think it is a problem about moments of the number of events that occur, i.e. related to $E[\binom{X}{k}]$, but I could not do the details. Could you please give me some hints? Thank you.

Comment: Did you notice that $X(X-1)\ldots (X-k+1) =k! \binom{X}{k} $?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Find $f(z):=E[z^X]$ and note that $$E[X(X-1)\cdots (X - k + 1)] = f^{(k)}(0).$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $X(X-1)...(X-k+1)=X^{\underline{k}}$. The probability generating function of a Poisson random variable $X$ with rate $\lambda$ is 
$$
G(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty P(X=k)t^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}t^k 
=\exp(\lambda (t-1)).
$$
Further
$$
E(X^{\underline{k}})=G^{(k)}(1).
$$
You should be able to take it from here.

Comment: What do you mean by $X(X-1)…(X-k+1) = X^k$ ?

Comment: @Longitude $X^{\underline{k}}$ (not $X^k$) is notation for $X(X-1)...(X-k+1)$ which is sometimes called the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)

Answer (score 0):

This identity has a combinatorial interpretation as well. The Poisson random variable is the limit of binomial random variables with $n$ trials and a $p = \frac{\lambda}{n}$ success probability, as $n \to \infty$. You can show that for a binomial random variable $\mathbf Y$,
$$
    \mathbb E\left[\binom{\mathbf Y}{k}\right] = \binom{n}{k} p^k 
$$
by linearity of expectation: $\binom{\mathbf Y}{k}$ counts (unordered) sets of $k$ successful trials. As $n \to \infty$, $\binom nk (\frac{\lambda}{n})^k \to \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$.